# Name the Game #1

Tags: video-games

<sub>This is part of a series of puzzles where you must identify the name of a video game</sub>

---

> In my books you must read
>   About a ship, clock and tree
>   One path is red, the other is blue
>   Which one you free is a choice made by you

**Name the video game**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> Myst

In my books you must read

> The books transport you to different ages

About a ship, clock and tree

> Each of the different ages

One path is red, the other blue

> Think this refers to the pages freeing the two brothers

Which one you free is a choice made by you

> You can pick which brother you free!

Comment: Well done! :) you got all the clues too!

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer

> The part about the red path and the blue path may be about the matrix. The video might be Enter the Matrix, though I don't know what the ship clock and tree or what the book part means.