# Name the Game #2

Tags: video-games

<sub>This is part of a series of puzzles where you must identify the name of a video game


Previous puzzle is here: [Name the Game #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79233/name-the-game-1)</sub>

---

> Turn the tap and open the valve
>   You won't have to face her by yourself
>   Something new comes out, oh it's blue!
>   Go for a bounce, you know you want to

**Name the video game**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> Portal 2

*Turn the tap and open the valve*

> Not 100% sure what this means, but Valve is the company who published Portal 2. Turning the tap could refer to the new gels which kinda look like they're coming out of faucets.

*You won't have to face her by yourself*

> Unlike Portal, when you face GladOS in Portal 2, you have Wheatley alongside you.

*Something new comes out, oh it's blue!
Go for a bounce, you know you want to*

> One of the additions made in Portal 2 are various gels throughout the facility. One of them, the repulsion gel, is blue and allows you to bounce around.

Comment: Well done, you got all the clues as well! :)