# Name the Game #3

Tags: video-games

<sub>This is part of a series of puzzles where you must identify the name of a video game


Previous puzzle is here: [Name the Game #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79256/name-the-game-2)</sub>

---

> Finding my cubes is key in this place
>   I could never exist in three-dimensional space
>   Some might call me the opposite of a room
>   But my exit is right there, get to it soon!

**Name the video game**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it

> Anti-chamber?

For the clues:

Finding my cubes is key in this place

> Progress involves finding different colored cubes that allow you further progress into the game

I could never exist in three-dimensional space

> A lot of the puzzles involve impossible spaces and using perspective to shift/connect isolated blocks

Some might call me the opposite of a room

> The opposite of a chamber is an anti-chamber

But my exit is right there, get to it soon!

> From what I remember, you start next to the exit but have to complete everything else before you're able to leave. And going fast is always good

Comment: Fantastic! Great solve :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Monument Valley

Finding my cubes is key in this place

> The game's stages are made of cubes (there might be more meaning to this but I can't find it)

I could never exist in three-dimensional space

> The gameplay revolves around "impossible shapes", such as the [Penrose Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_triangle)

Some might call me the opposite of a room

> Not sure, but most stages take place in a floating landscape, not a room

But my exit is right there, get to it soon!

> Each level is completed by reaching the exit. It is in plain sight but the path there can be tricky.

Comment: Okay nevermind, late and incorrect.