# Name the Game #4

Tags: video-games

<sub>This is part of a series of puzzles where you must identify the name of a video game


Previous puzzle is here: [Name the Game #3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79294/name-the-game-3)</sub>

---

> I suggest you bring an umbrella
>   While you look for a little fella
>   I could kill folded paper
>   But will I get away with this caper?

**Name the video game**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it:

> Heavy rain?

Because:

> You need an umbrella in the rain. You're looking for your son Shaun. The origama killer leaves origami at the crime scene. Some of the options when playing through require you to dance?

Comment: this is better then mine (+1)

Comment: Nicely done! Although for the last line I was more thinking of rot13(Vg'f gur cynlre'f pubvpr nf gb jurgure gur Bevtnzv Xvyyre trgf njnl jvgu vg)

Comment: Fair enough that does make more sense. I just remember pulling out all my stunning dance moves as Madison lol

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Paper Mario?

because

> You look for Bowser to save peach and get colour back (:looking for this this fella". Bowser is telling this poem about himself in third person), there is paper (**paper** mario) and there is lots of paint so you might need an umbrella to protect yourself from all the paint?